# Completely compromise restricted access to methods in plain java using reflection - why is that possible?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm totally puzzled - I wrote a class in Java8 SE (less than 10 lines of code) which completely compromises restricted (private) methods using reflection. I find this is very dangerous and question the sense of reflection allowing this.

```
package reflection;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Reflection {

    //  Throw 'Throwable' because this method must be totally transparent, doing exactly what the actually called method does:
    static public Object call(Object target, String methodName, Object... args) throws Throwable {

        // Get the arguments' classes:
        Class<?>[] argumentClasses =
                Arrays.asList(args)
                    .stream()
                    .map(object -> object.getClass())
                    .toArray(Class[]::new);

        Method method = target.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, argumentClasses);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return method.invoke(target, args);
    }

}
```

You can run this tests, which calls private methods - both static and non-static - of another class, Action:

```
package reflection;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ReflectionUnitTest {

    @Test
    public void testCall() throws Throwable {

        Action target = new Action();

        assertEquals("Something static done!", Reflection.call(target, "doSomethingStatic"));
        assertEquals("Something static done with something else!", Reflection.call(target, "doSomethingStatic", "something else"));
        assertEquals("Something static done 3 times with something else!", Reflection.call(target, "doSomethingStatic", 3, "something else"));
        assertEquals("Something static done 5 times with something else!", Reflection.call(target, "doSomethingStatic", "something else", 5));

        assertEquals("Something done!", Reflection.call(target, "doSomething"));
        assertEquals("Something done with something else!", Reflection.call(target, "doSomething", "something else"));
        assertEquals("Something done 3 times with something else!", Reflection.call(target, "doSomething", 3, "something else"));
        assertEquals("Something done 5 times with something else!", Reflection.call(target, "doSomething", "something else", 5));
    }

}


package reflection;

public class Action {

    static private String doSomethingStatic(){

        return "Something static done!";
    }

    private String doSomethingStatic(String argument) {

        return "Something static done with " + argument + "!";
    }

    private String doSomethingStatic(Integer count, String argument) {

        return "Something static done " + count + " times with " + argument + "!";
    }

    private String doSomethingStatic(String argument, Integer count) {

        return "Something static done " + count + " times with " + argument + "!";
    }


    private String doSomething() {

        return "Something done!";
    }

    private String doSomething(String argument) {

        return "Something done with " + argument + "!";
    }

    private String doSomething(Integer count, String argument) {

        return "Something done " + count + " times with " + argument + "!";
    }

    private String doSomething(String argument, Integer count) {

        return "Something done " + count + " times with " + argument + "!";
    }

}
```

My issues:

1. To share this knowledge with you
2. To ask if anybody can explain why this is possible

Comment: It's possible because you've not got a `SecurityManager` which forbids it. The fact that you can access `private` things in this way is hardly a secret (and is documented in the [`setAccessible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)) method's Javadoc).

Comment: Yes, but then, shouldn't there be a default SecurityManager in place which prohibits this? I have never dealed with SecurityManagers as I expected 'private' and 'protected' to be sufficiently secure by themselves.

Comment: Reflection is the a way that Java allow you "hack", like the famous quote says "a great power require a great responsibility" so if you use it, be aware of what you´re doing, because obviously the developer that put that access private most probably he did for a reason.

Comment: Beyond that - is there anything I can do to make my answer also upvote worthy in your eyes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not reflection.

The problem lies within your assumptions/expectations.

Let me explain: unless your application runs on your own physical hardware, that nobody else has access too; and unless you control all aspects of the code load on the system that runs your application ... control is an **illusion** anyway.

If your classes run on a JVM that doesn't "belong" you ... people can do (almost)  whatever they want to do anyway. It is only a matter of effort.

Meaning: the fathers of the Java language enabled reflection at some point; and for good or bad, they decided to allow you to override this protection (if there isn't a SecurityManager in place). But that is nothing new, it has been like that since the beginnings.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you find it dangerous... why? If you call a private code and its go BOOM, it will be YOUR program that will crash. The caller code is the one that will have to handle the exceptions... So, if not for security, why `private` exists?

They exist in order to express **intent**. They exist to tell the users of the code what are the methods that they should use, what are the ones that they should use only when subclassing and the ones that they should not use at all, because doing so will cause problems.

The developer of the original code does not expect another developer to call the private method directly because maybe doing so will skip some validations and will give wrong results.

Or maybe you cannot change directly one variable because it must also change another one... but if is exactly that other variable the one giving you trouble, setting it directly by reflection will skip the problem...

So, calling privates by reflection isn't for defeating security measures, it is for making workarounds on bad design decisions (which may be on the `private` part, the design should have allowed a direct call, or may be on the reflection part, and you should not be calling the private methods because that will make YOUR code behave incorrectly).

Comment: What's the use of expressing an intent when it can easily be violated or ignored? I find it dangerous because via reflection I can reveal things the original designer decided to hide or encapsulate, maybe passwords, user credentials, or restricted data not meant to be accessed by everybody. It's wierd that you find reflection is a good way for 'correcting' badly designed code. I think it's a too easy way for hacking things.

Comment: The point that you're missing is that passwords and users credentials shouldn't be on the code, they should be on a separated file or database, encrypted. The code is just as safe as the computer it's runs on, and it's not unsafe because private were never meant to be a security measure. Even if there is a password on the private code, what prevents you from just directly reading it from the .dll?